# allow system to support multiple languages

Tags: web2py

How to use T.force('ar') to allow the system support multiple language.

i have two links into my page when Arabic link is pressed the system will converted to Arabic version and also when English link is pressed the system will converted to English version.

how to force language on click of link??

and also how can i allow data into database to be translated using "T"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In web2py. Make a model that contains something like

```
if re.compile('\w{2}(\-\w{2})?').match(request.vars.force_language or ''): 
    session.forced_language=force_language
if session.forced_language:
   T.force(session.forced_language)
```

the call any of the page with

```
http://....../index?force_language=ar
```

The system will store it in session and remember your preference. Will translate if languages/ar.py exists.